# Масштабирование битмапа

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

Создаю битмап так

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_event_place);
```

Использую `Matrix` для настройки местоположения и размера битмапа.

```
 mMatrix.setScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
 mMatrix.setTranslate(mStartX + (radius - paint.getStrokeWidth() / 2),
                mStartY - mBitmap.getHeight() / 1.5f);
 canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, mBitmapPaint);
```

Кисть, которой рисую битмап

```
mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mBitmapPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
mBitmapPaint.setDither(true);
```

Битмап рисуется, `mMatrix.setTranslate()` работает как надо, а `mMatrix.setScale(1.5f, 1.5f)` не работает вообще, с любыми параметрами.

`setScale(float sx, float sy, float px, float py)` и 
`postScale()` тоже не работают

Comment: А `preScale()` ? И ещё один нюанс есть - битмап, декодированный таким способом "подгоняется" под параметры дисплея, может быть в этом причина.

Comment: `preScale` тоже не работает, про декодирование действительно возможно, но я вот смотрю пример и там также декодировано, и почему то работает, может обновилось что-то

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда вы применяете друг за другом методы [setScale](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setScale(float,%20float)) и [setTranslate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setTranslate(float,%20float)) и им подобные, результат предыдущих применений сбрасывается последующими. Чтобы учесть оба преобразования нужно пользоваться методами pre*() и post*(). Вот так:

```
mMatrix.setScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
mMatrix.postTranslate(mStartX + (radius - paint.getStrokeWidth() / 2),
                mStartY - mBitmap.getHeight() / 1.5f);
```

Comment: да, действительно